# Pass by reference in Red routines

Tags: red, red-system

So I'm currently in the process of migrating a descent sized program from Rebol 3 to Red.  Said program relies on a large binding to a C library (clang).  I have rewritten the binding portion in Red/System, and am interfacing that code with Red through wrapper routines.  The current convention I have been using is to cast the pointers and void pointers needed as parameters and returned by the C code to red/system integers and box them up as Red integers.  This is fairly easy and convenient.

Since I can only access the raw integer! data instead of the actual struct, I would suspect then that I can't pass a pointer back out through a parameter (as the boxed data is being copied before being passed) using the above methodology, anymore.

So, is there a recommended methodology to passing pointers back out through parameters, aka how do we pass by reference with routines?

```
twiddle: routine [
    arg [integer!]
    return: [integer!]
] [
    arg: 321
    test: declare struct! [
        dummy [integer!]
    ]
    test/dummy: 456
    as integer! test
]

a: 123
b: twiddle a

print a ;If I could pass by reference this would be 321
print b
```

Comment: Could you edit to provide your code that worked before but does not work now, and mention specific version numbers that changed behavior?

Comment: I think actually what might have happened is that the old version I was using may have been an automated build with broken marshaling, as I've gone back through and checked previous release versions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you do `twiddle a`, your are not passing the word `a` to the function, but its value. Words in Rebol-like languages are not exactly *variables* like in many other languages. They are first class values that can reference other values inside a context, aka *namespace*. So a word does not hold any value, it points to a context table that holds the value. You can picture a context as a table with two columns, the left column contain words, the right column holds their respective value.

So, strickly speaking, there is no "passing by reference", you can only manipulate *values* at Red level, and those values are always copied from the context table to the Red internal stack. If you want to change the value referred by `a`, you need to set `a` to that new value. That could be also achieved at Red/System level using the Red runtime API, but that API is currently informal and not fully stabilized (but anyway heavily used internally).

One good way to handle your needs is to build a block of values instead of assigning individual values to words, but I do not know enough of what you want to achieve to be sure it would be a good fit.

So after this preamble, to answer your question more directly: you cannot pass by reference to a routine, you can only pass by value (either getting a marshalled value, or getting a pointer to the boxed value **on stack**, and not in the context table). If that value happens to be a series like a block! for example, then you can modify its content from the routine (like changing, adding, removing elements).

Anyway, if you really want to change the value referenced by a word from within a routine, here is how to achieve it:

```
twiddle: routine [
    w [word!]
    return: [integer!]
    /local test
] [
    test: declare struct! [
        dummy [integer!]
    ]
    test/dummy: 456
    _context/set w as red-value! integer/box as-integer test
    as integer! test
]

a: 123
b: twiddle 'a
```

As you can see, you need to pass an unevaluated word (a lit-word!), and then set its value from the routine in order to achieve the side-effect you were expecting. That is not the recommended way though, better use a block! or an object! to push values from the Red/System level to Red level, or just assign the returned value to a word, as you do for `b`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Doc!  I figured as much, I just didn't know how to set the value in the context.  At this point I'm just trying to keep the Red code as close as possible to the Rebol, and then once its functional start refactoring things to be more "proper".

Comment: @johnk Thanks for the typos fixing. :-)