# Pointers returned from dll function when called from rebol

Tags: dll, rebol, rebol2

I am trying to ascertain weather I can use rebol for a few programming tasks. I have written a small program which loads an external library and calls a function which returns pointers in some of the arguments. When I run the program it crashes rebol.exe. I am hoping somebody can help  me out.
The dll function is as follows:

```
void xxx swe_utc_time_zone(int32 iyear, int32 imonth, int32 iday, 
int32 ihour, int32 imin, double dsec, double dtimezone, 
int32 *iyear_utc, int32 *imonth_utc, int32 *iday_utc, 
int32 *ihour_utc, int32 *imin_utc, double *dsec_utc)
```

and this is my small test program:

```
rebol []
astrology-lib: load/library %/c/sweph/bin/swedll32.dll
swe-utc-time-zone: make routine! [
   iyear [integer!]
   imonth [integer!]
   iday [integer!]
   ihour [integer!]
   iminute [integer!]
   dsec [decimal!]
   dtimezone [decimal!]
   iyear-utc [char*]
   imonth-utc [char*]
   iday-utc [char*]
   ihour-utc [char*]
   iminute-utc [char*]
   dsec-utc [char*]
] astrology-lib "_swe_utc_time_zone@60"
swe-utc-time-zone 2015 6 20 0 19 0 -4.5 none none none none none none
```

The program crashes on the last line where I attempt to call the function. The error message is "REBOL/View system has stopped working"

Comment: There are a few more examples of calling out to libraries over here http://www.re-bol.com/rebol.html#section-9.8

Comment: @johnk  There's nothing there that uses pointer parameters and I feel that is where the error is.

Comment: The stars predict more interesting luck with the FFI implementation ([foreign function interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface)) for ROUTINE! that is in Atronix's fork of Rebol3.  *(Also rebol3 is open source, and has a more likely future.)*  I don't know much about it, but [test file here](https://github.com/zsx/r3/blob/atronix/make/tests/test-ffi.r) and you might ask them if you have problems.  [Download page](http://atronixengineering.com/downloads.html)  See also: [Red](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30087380/)

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide memory with at least the same size as the pointer you want to get back from your call.

So instead of **none** you should use words initialized with something along the line of

```
iyear-utc: make struct! [
    point [integer!]
] none
```

Maybe these links will give you more help [adress](http://www.rebol.org/view-script.r?script=addr.r), [conversions](http://www.rebol.net/cgi-bin/r3blog.r?view=0056), [more conversions](http://www.rebol.net/cgi-bin/r3blog.r?view=0056)